# simplification of multivariable equations

Tags: mathematica

Can anybody suggest me any method to simplify this equation?

[This is the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjA0x.jpg) with conditions:  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{i=4}\lambda_{i}^{2} = 1$ and $0≤\lambda_{i} ≤ 1$ (as they are probability amplitudes).

I have tried the simplification using algebraic identities, but the complexity of the equation (in terms of number of terms) is almost same. I have also tried some mathematical tool like "MATHEMATICA" for the simplification, that is also giving the same result.

Does there exist a mathematical tool for the simplification of such multivariable complex equations?